# Сортировка по принципу домино

Tags: python, сортировка

Доброго времени суток. Помогите решить задачу, ну или в каком месте копать? (гугл не помог)

Есть список граней: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Есть список вершин от граней: [(2, 6), (3, 7), (8, 2), (8, 3), (6, 9), (7, 9)]
(где индекс пары вершин соответствует индексу грани)

Задача: отсортировать грани по условию общих вершин. Если грань имеет общую вершину с проверяемой – добавляем в список. При этом соблюдая последовательность.

К примеру:

грани (2, 6) и (6, 9) имеют общую вершину 6, в список (1)

грани (6, 9) и (7, 9) имеют общую вершину 9, в список (1, 5)

грани (7, 9) и (3, 7) имеют общую вершину 7, в список (1, 5, 6)

и т.д.

выход: [1, 5, 6, 2, 4, 3]

Как такую проверку выразить в коде ?

Answer (score 0):

Грани и вершины, говоришь? а как по мне, так это обычный граф, только в необычной интерпретации - рёбра пронумерованы числами и названы гранями, а узлы названы вершинами и определяются набором выходящих из узла рёбер (и что примечательно - все узлы поголовно исключительно дуальные).

Так что смени терминологию и используй обычные алгоритмы обхода ненаправленного графа.

Comment: На самом деле это могли быть и палочки/камешки, не в этом суть. Взял с оригинала vertex и edge, связанно с 3D. За направление спасибо, буду смотреть в DFS.

Comment: upd: привык к английской терминологии vertex/face/edge и при переводе перепутал их. Смотрю на edge, называю грань, в место ребро, facepalm.